# chrome.desktopCapture - remote screen sharing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, webrtc

I have quick question - can I use `chrome.desktopCapture` Google Chrome feature to share screen with other users? If it is possible how can I do it, maybe any example? I know how to capture my screen and display it on my computer. But how to do this with other users via Internet?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API

Answer (score 1):

Based from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture), `chrome.desktopCapture` is only used to capture content of screen, individual windows or tabs. As stated by @Daniel Herr, you can use [WebRTC API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Screensharing-with-WebRTC). You can check this [sample code](https://github.com/samdutton/rtcshare) and [Quick Start Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1idl_NYQhllFEFqkGQOLv8KBK8M3EVzyvxnKkHl4SuM8/edit).